# Spring RabbitMQ Consumer - Multiple Instances

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq

I created a Spring Boot application that creates a queue to consume from a RabbitMQ Topic Exchange. Now I would like to be able to run multiple instances of this app for high availability and load balancing. However, I noticed that when I post a message on the queue, both applications are processing the message. Is there a way to configure the queue/app such that a message is only consumed by one of the identical applications?

Please find my configuration below:

```
 @Bean
  public TopicExchange dLQExchange() {
    return ExchangeBuilder.topicExchange("queue.dlq").build();
  }

  @Bean
  Queue dlq() {
    return QueueBuilder.durable("queue.dlq").build();
  }

  @Bean
  Queue queue() {
    return QueueBuilder.durable("queue")
            .deadLetterExchange("queue.dlq")
            .build();
  }

  @Bean
  public Binding dlqBinding(TopicExchange dLQExchange, Queue dlq) {
    return BindingBuilder.bind(dlq).to(dLQExchange).with("#");
  }

  @Bean
  public TopicExchange producerExchange() {
    return ExchangeBuilder.topicExchange("producer.exchange").build();
  }

  @Bean
  public Binding producer(
          TopicExchange producerExchange, Queue queue) {
    return BindingBuilder.bind(queue)
            .to(producerExchange)
            .with("queue.updated");
  }

  @Bean
  public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
    rabbitTemplate.setMessageConverter(producerJackson2MessageConverter());
    return rabbitTemplate;
  }

  @Bean
  public Jackson2JsonMessageConverter producerJackson2MessageConverter() {
    return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
  }
```

Comment: This sounds like a somewhat strange or unexpected result.  AFAIK once some process consumes a message on a JMS queue, it should be removed and not readable by anyone else.

Comment: I just realised that the producer was sending two ideantical messages. I spent a whole day pouring over this and I obviously realise it immediatly after posting, typical :/